# Change default mouse over response Zkoss

Tags: html, zk

Hi can anyone help me remove the default behavior of the mouse over event on a row in Zkoss?

This event changes the color of the row and with my background it becomes illegible.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Well what do you need?
Removing the whole hoover event or changing the backgroiund?

For changing the background selected row use this :

```
<style>       
  .z-listitem:hover .z-listcell-content {background-color:#ff0000;}
</style>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/144129u/39-Change-background-color-selected-item-from-listbox) where you see how you can change hover color and noram background color.

Comment: [Issue I'm having](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1p0i1mc/6-My-issue)

As you can see the background color doesn't fill the entire content of each row and the text color also changes from white to gray.

Comment: Press f12 in browser and look up the CSS classes where you need changes. Pretty easy once you understand it

Comment: The issue is I can't figure out who's responsible for it. Like I've tried to change the background-clip option but it doesn't work.